# Interaction between Pydantic models/schemas in the FastAPI Tutorial

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I follow the [FastAPI Tutorial](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#review-all-the-files) and am not quite sure what the exact relationship between the proposed data objects is.

We have the `models.py` file:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from .database import Base


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True)
    hashed_password = Column(String)
    is_active = Column(Boolean, default=True)

    items = relationship("Item", back_populates="owner")


class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = "items"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, index=True)
    description = Column(String, index=True)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))

    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="items")
```

And the `schemas.py` file:

```py
from typing import List, Union

from pydantic import BaseModel


class ItemBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    description: Union[str, None] = None


class ItemCreate(ItemBase):
    pass


class Item(ItemBase):
    id: int
    owner_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    email: str


class UserCreate(UserBase):
    password: str


class User(UserBase):
    id: int
    is_active: bool
    items: List[Item] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Those classes are then used to define db queries like in the `crud.py` file:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from . import models, schemas


def get_user(db: Session, user_id: int):
    return db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == user_id).first()


def get_user_by_email(db: Session, email: str):
    return db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.email == email).first()


def get_users(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.User).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()


def create_user(db: Session, user: schemas.UserCreate):
    fake_hashed_password = user.password + "notreallyhashed"
    db_user = models.User(email=user.email, hashed_password=fake_hashed_password)
    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_user)
    return db_user

def get_items(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.Item).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()

def create_user_item(db: Session, item: schemas.ItemCreate, user_id: int):
    db_item = models.Item(**item.dict(), owner_id=user_id)
    db.add(db_item)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_item)
    return db_item
```

And in the FastAPI code `main.py`:

```py
from typing import List

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from . import crud, models, schemas
from .database import SessionLocal, engine

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI()


# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


@app.post("/users/", response_model=schemas.User)
def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = crud.get_user_by_email(db, email=user.email)
    if db_user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Email already registered")
    return crud.create_user(db=db, user=user)


@app.get("/users/", response_model=List[schemas.User])
def read_users(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    users = crud.get_users(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return users


@app.get("/users/{user_id}", response_model=schemas.User)
def read_user(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = crud.get_user(db, user_id=user_id)
    if db_user is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")
    return db_user


@app.post("/users/{user_id}/items/", response_model=schemas.Item)
def create_item_for_user(
    user_id: int, item: schemas.ItemCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)
):
    return crud.create_user_item(db=db, item=item, user_id=user_id)


@app.get("/items/", response_model=List[schemas.Item])
def read_items(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    items = crud.get_items(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return items
```

**From what I understand:**

- The `models` data classes define the SQL tables.
- The `schemas` data classes define the API that FastAPI uses to interact with the database.
- They must be convertible into each other so that the set-up works.

**What I don't understand:**

- In `crud.create_user_item` I expected the return type to be `schemas.Item`, since that return type is used by FastAPI again.
- According to my understanding the response model of `@app.post("/users/{user_id}/items/", response_model=schemas.Item)` in the `main.py` is wrong, or how can I understand the return type inconsistency?
- However inferring from the code, the actual return type must be `models.Item`, how is that handled by FastAPI?
- What would be the return type of `crud.get_user`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'll go through your bullet points one by one.

---

> The `models` data classes define the SQL tables.

Yes. More precisely, the [orm](/questions/tagged/orm) classes that map to actual database tables are defined in the [`models`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-the-database-models) module.

---

> The `schemas` data classes define the API that FastAPI uses to interact with the database.

Yes and no. The Pydantic models in the [`schemas`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-the-pydantic-models) module define the data schemas relevant to the API, yes. But that has nothing to do with the database yet. Some of these schemas define what data is **expected** to be **received** by certain API endpoints for the request to be considered **valid**. Others define what the data **returned** by certain endpoints will look like.

---

> They must be convertible into each other so that the set-up works.

While the database table schemas and the API data schemas are usually very similar, that is not necessarily the case. In the tutorial however, they correspond quite neatly, which allows succinct [crud](/questions/tagged/crud) code, like [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-data):

```py
db_item = models.Item(**item.dict(), owner_id=user_id)
```

Here `item` is a Pydantic model instance, i.e. one of [your API data schemas](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-initial-pydantic-models-schemas) `schemas.ItemCreate` containing data you decided is necessary for creating a new item. Since its fields (their names and types) correspond to [those of the database model](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-model-attributescolumns) `models.Item`, the latter can be instantiated from the dictionary representation of the former (with the addition of the `owner_id`).

---

> In `crud.create_user_item` I expected the return type to be `schemas.Item`, since that return type is used by FastAPI again.

No, this is exactly the magic of FastAPI. The function `create_user_item` returns an instance of `models.Item`, i.e. the ORM object as constructed from the database (after calling `session.refresh` on it):

```py
def create_user_item(db: Session, item: schemas.ItemCreate, user_id: int):
    db_item = models.Item(**item.dict(), owner_id=user_id)
    ...
    return db_item
```

**And** [the API route handler function](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-your-fastapi-path-operations) `create_item_for_user` actually does return that same object (of class `models.Item`).

```py
@app.post("/users/{user_id}/items/", response_model=schemas.Item)
def create_item_for_user(
    user_id: int, item: schemas.ItemCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)
):
    return crud.create_user_item(db=db, item=item, user_id=user_id)
```

**However**, the `@app.post` decorator takes that object and uses it to construct an instance of the [**`response_model`**](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/#response_model-parameter) you defined for that route, which is `schemas.Item` in this case. This is why you [set `orm_mode`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#use-pydantics-orm_mode) in your `schemas.Item` model:

```py
class Config:
    orm_mode = True
```

This allows an instance of that class to be created via the [`.from_orm`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.6/concepts/models/#arbitrary-class-instances) method. (This only applies to Pydantic v1 Models.) That all happens behind the scenes and again depends on the SQLAlchemy model corresponding to the Pydantic model with regards to field names and types. Otherwise validation fails.

---

> According to my understanding the response model [...] is wrong

No, see above. The **decorated** route function actually returns an instance of the `schemas.Item` model.

---

> However inferring from the code, the actual return type must be `models.Item`

Yes, see above. The return type of the undecorated route handler function `create_item_for_user` is in fact `models.Item`. **But its return type is not the response model.**

I assume that to reduce confusion the documentation example does not annotate the return type of those route functions. If it did, it would look like this:

```py
@app.post("/users/{user_id}/items/", response_model=schemas.Item)
def create_item_for_user(
    user_id: int, item: schemas.ItemCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)
) -> models.Item:
    return crud.create_user_item(db=db, item=item, user_id=user_id)
```

It may help to remember that a [function decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator) is just syntactic sugar for a function that takes a function as argument and (usually) returns a function. Typically the returned function actually *internally* calls the function passed to it as argument and does additional things before and/or after that call. I could rewrite the route above like this and it would be exactly the same:

```py
def create_item_for_user(
    user_id: int, item: schemas.ItemCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)
) -> models.Item:
    return crud.create_user_item(db=db, item=item, user_id=user_id)


create_item_for_user = app.post(
    "/users/{user_id}/items/", response_model=schemas.Item
)(create_item_for_user)
```

---

> What would be the return type of `crud.get_user`?

That would be `models.User` because that is the database model and is what the `first` method of that query returns.

```py
def get_user(db: Session, user_id: int) -> models.User:
    return db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == user_id).first()
```

This is then again returned by the `read_user` API route function in the same fashion as I explained above for `models.Item`.

```py
@app.get("/users/{user_id}", response_model=schemas.User)
def read_user(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)) -> models.User:
    db_user = crud.get_user(db, user_id=user_id)
    ...
    return db_user  # <-- instance of `models.User`
```

That is, the `models.User` object is intercepted by the internal function of the decorator and (because of the defined `response_model`) passed to `schemas.User.from_orm`, which returns a `schemas.User` object.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for this clear and thorough answer!

Comment: This could be part of the FastAPI / Pydantic documentation / tutorial. Very clear!

Comment: Superb answer! Thanks @Daniil Fajnberg and also to patrick for asking